# No package wget available when I install wget

Tags: centos, wget, yum

In my CentOS 6.5, I want to install the wget:

```
#  yum -y install wget
```

But I get the below error:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]#  yum -y install wget
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
No package wget available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Edit your question and put the output of `yum repolist`

Comment: did you manage to get this resolved?

Comment: @user3788685 The yum source is problematic, I change it to a impeccable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be missing the 'base' repo from your yum config.

```
yum info wget
 * base: mirrors.melbourne.co.uk
Installed Packages
Name        : wget
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.12
Release     : 10.el6
Size        : 1.8 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : A utility for retrieving files using the HTTP or FTP protocols
URL         : http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/
License     : GPLv3+ and GFDL
Description : GNU Wget is a file retrieval utility which can use either the HTTP or
            : FTP protocols. Wget features include the ability to work in the
            : background while you are logged out, recursive retrieval of
            : directories, file name wildcard matching, remote file timestamp
            : storage and comparison, use of Rest with FTP servers and Range with
            : HTTP servers to retrieve files over slow or unstable connections,
            : support for Proxy servers, and configurability.
```

It sounds like you may be missing the 'CentOS-Base' repo from your config. Check in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` If it doesn't exist then create it and add the following config block;

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

You can also find the package via http://rpm.pbone.net